# Can i use "let" to define an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tried doing

```js
"use strict"
let iterable = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]);

for (let entry of iterable) {
  console.log(entry);
}
```

But getting the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode(…)

This piece of code throws error when trying in the chrome browser console

Is anything i'm missing here

Comment: Is `use strict` at the beginning of a function declaration?

Comment: Your use strict statement really should have a semicolon.  Is that all the code in the file? Do you have anything before the strict line?

Comment: I don't get an error when I use `Run code snippet`. `"use strict"` has to be at the beginning of the source file or function definition. Just typing it in the console doesn't work.

Comment: It  works on Firefox

Comment: Works on chrome, too

Comment: Actually had tried with the semicolon also, but same error. Missed it while posting @epascarello

Comment: The semicolon won't make a difference WRT your issue. Why does it matter if it works in chrome's console or not?

Comment: I *think* I remember hearing that Chrome's console operates inside of a `with` statement. I wonder if that makes a difference. When I test other code in the console using `"use strict";`, it doesn't give strict-mode behavior, so I'm guessing it just removes the declarative.

Comment: Yep, I think that's it, coupled with Chrome simply not yet being complete in their ES6 implementation. Wrap the code in an *IIFE*, and it works in the console: `(function() { "use strict"; /*your code*/ })()`

Answer (score 3):

The reason this doesn't work in Google Chrome out of the box is because Chrome doesn't support *some* ES6 features by default, and flags any attempt of using it as an error.

You *can* set your Google Chrome browser to allow the use of ES6 from going to this link and enabling the setting `Enable Experimental JavaScript`:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony
```

**Note:**

This may be a particular issue depending on your version of Google Chrome, however if you're getting this error then enabling this flag should help.

Comment: I think they dropped the need for that flag a while back, but Chrome isn't fully compliant yet.

Comment: @MikeC It probably depends on your version of Google Chrome for which features are disallowed by default

Comment: @squint I tried running OP's code in my Chrome console, got his error, and enabled the harmony flag, relaunched Chrome, and then it worked for me personally

Comment: I see. So they must have bleeding edge features still behind that flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run you script from js file. You'll see it's working. You can't access strict mode directly from the console. That's why you script is not working. 
And you definitely don't need any flags be enabled. Chrome supports let declaration from the box.